# Using redirectInput {id} parameter

Tags: redirect

I have a public registration form and want to redirect to a payment page where I will need some details about the newly created user. I tried doing this in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
{{ redirectInput('join/payment/?user={id}') }}
```

I have set a custom route to allow for the query parameter:

```
   if url = join/payment/*  load template join/payment
```

but the resulting url does not include the query string, just the first two segments, 'join/payment'.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question to share the custom route definition you've created?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, false alarm. My template file was not syncing with the server. To recap, this works like a charm:

```
{{ redirectInput('join/payment/{id}') }}
```

This results in a redirect that includes the ID of the entry or user that was just created!